# How to allow anonymous user access from localhost only in Spring security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I want to allow only requests from localhost for a specific URL pattern. I tried this so far:

```
<sec:intercept-url pattern="/blabla/**" access="hasIpAddress('127.0.0.1')" />
```

But this isn't working and I got the following statement in the log output:

```
Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point
```

So my question is, how do I allow anonymous user access from localhost only?

Comment: Try adding port number with IP `<sec:intercept-url pattern="/blabla/**" access="hasIpAddress('127.0.0.1:portnumber')" />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to express this and() relation in XML based configuration?

As per documentation here https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/el-access.html below should work.

Here we have defined that the “blabla” area of an application (defined by the URL pattern) should only be available to anonymous users whose IP address matches 127.0.0.1.

```
    <sec:intercept-url pattern="/blabla/**"
        access="isAnonymous() and hasIpAddress('127.0.0.1')"/>
```

Comment: when I tried using `hasIpAddress('127.0.0.1')` only it allowed access from IP address but was denying access from `localhost`. I made it work by adding the IP6 version of it too `hasIpAddress('127.0.0.1') or hasIpAddress('::1')`

Answer (score 6):

I ended up using the following:

```
http.authorizeRequests()
// restrict all requests unless coming from localhost IP4 or IP6
.antMatchers("/**").access("hasIpAddress(\"127.0.0.1\") or hasIpAddress(\"::1\")")
```

I tried only with `hasIpAddress("127.0.0.1")` which was working ok if I put that IP in the browser url but it wasn't working with requesting it from `localhost` as an alias.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [`HttpSecurity::anonymous`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.12.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/builders/HttpSecurity.html) method enabling and providing the [`AnonymousConfigurer<H extends HttpSecurityBuilder<H>>`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.12.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/config/annotation/web/configurers/AnonymousConfigurer.html) configuration of the  anonymous authentication.

At your Spring Security configuration class, there should be an overriding method:

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.and()
        .anonymous()...          // enables and configures the anonymous access
    .and()
        .authorizeRequests()...
```

Comment: Is it possible to express this `and()` relation in XML based configuration?